# Is HTML pop-up tool available in ArcReader?

Tags: arcreader, arcgis-publisher, arcgis-10.4, html-popup

I've published a water and sewer map that has as-built plans in PMF format attached to a buffer feature class around the utilities' piping. When I open the published map in ArcReader I can access the PMFs using the identify tool. I read on ESRI's blog that the attachments can also be accessed using the HTML pop-up tool.

***"HTML pop-ups are a useful way to view multiple attachments for a feature at the same time. They work not only in ArcGIS Desktop but also in web applications, ArcGIS Explorer, or ArcReader."***

I cannot find the tool in ArcReader. Am I missing it or is it just not available in ArcReader?

I am using ArcMap 10.4.0.5524 and ArcReader 10.4. The blog that I read saying that HTML pop-up was available in ArcReader was dated [Spring of 2011](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0311/more-ways-to-organize-information.html).

Comment: I've just tried by adding attachments and a layer to publisher and creating PMF.  I can see them all fine in ArcMap but like you I cannot get it to output in ArcReader.  Maybe this functionality never made it to ArcReader?  It doesn't seem to be a well supported part of the ArcGIS family.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is "NO", it is not possible.

However, there is an ArcGIS Idea to have this implemented: [Be able to view HTML popups in ArcReader](http://esri.ideadev2.cs14.force.com/ideaView?id=087c0000000CatAAAS)

Using HTML popups in ArcMap also supports this function in ArcGIS Explorer when packgaging layers.

ArcReader has no support at this stage (at version 10) for HTML popups.

Answer (score 2):

This morning I was told by our ESRI account manager that this function is not available in ArcReader. That ArcReader has not seen much development in the last few years since most users are trending towards a web or collector standard.

Answer (score 1):

A "work-a-round" would be to place all of your html documents in one folder, list the html documents in a related table with the document path and setup hyperlinks to the related records.  When you do an identify on the record/feature you can select the hyperlink and open the html document.  Not quite the same as using a html pop-up, but will provide a link to external documents.  This also works for pdf's and other document types.  ArcGIS Standard is required for creating the related table relationship.